# JRuby GUI Window

Tags: java, ruby, user-interface, jruby, desktop-application

I'm just trying to create a simple graphics window using JRuby. So I installed JRuby and am using rubymine IDE. I have this piece of code:

```
include Java

import java.awt.Color
import javax.swing.ImageIcon
import javax.swing.JLabel
import javax.swing.JPanel
import javax.swing.JFrame

class Graphics < JFrame
  def initialize
    super "Absolute"
    self.initUI
  end

  def initUI
    panel = JPanel.new
    panel.setLayout nil
    panel.setBackground Color.new 66, 66, 66
    self.getContentPane.add panel

    self.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    self.setSize 350, 300
    self.setLocationRelativeTo nil
    self.setVisible true
  end
end
```

I run this and it compiles with no errors. RubyMine says:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But nothing happens, I don't see any window at all. How do I get a simple graphics window to appear? Thanks

Comment: You've defined a class, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just defines a class and then hits the end of file, so it exits. Try creating an instance at the end, with `Graphics.new`.